# Is this verse about fire contradicting science?

Tags: quran, tafseer, islamic-philosophy

I have a question about surah alwaqia verse

> {أَ فَرَأَيْتُمُ النَّارَ الَّتِي تُورُونَ_ أَ أَنْتُمْ أَنْشَأْتُمْ شَجَرَتَها أَمْ نَحْنُ الْمُنْشِؤُنَ } 71- 72

Tell me about the fire which you kindle-have you raised it’s tree or have we raised it.

I think this verse is saying that the fire is made just from the tree, and without it we can’t make the fire ( of course in the past era people were making fire from woods ) and this verse is about them and it says that we are made the tree which you make fire by that and you aren’t the builder of the tree and if we didn’t make it you couldn’t make the fire.

But today we make fire in our kitchen without any wood and tree 
 A 100 years who we made fire by matches which were built from tree but today we can make it by a lighter , and we doesn’t need a tree or wood. 
Is this a contradiction?

Comment: The verse is addressing the Arabs of the time of the prophet pbuh, and they were addressed with what they understand. So there's no contradiction as we must interpret it newly for our purposes.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no contradiction. There is nothing in the verses you quoted that says wood is the **only** source of fire; it is one of the sources. There is no use of any exclusivity device in the verses:

> أَفَرَأَيْتُمُ النَّارَ الَّتِي تُورُونَ أَأَنتُمْ أَنشَأْتُمْ شَجَرَتَهَا أَمْ نَحْنُ الْمُنشِئُونَ
>
> And have you seen the fire that you ignite? Is it you who produced its tree, or are We the producer?
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Waqi'ah 56:71-72](https://quran.com/56/71-72)</sub>

Comment: Okay I know that but if I make fire by a lighter , it’s me who produced the lighter.

Comment: Not exactly. The lighter is made of plastic and metal and contains gas. These come from oil byproducts and mines, none of which you yourself produced. Neither have you produced the oxygen that enables you to light the fire. And again, lighter is another option; there is no exclusivity still.

Comment: okay ya you’re right this is not me who produces the oxygen-gas and plastic and these are not my production .it was clear and I accepted , thank u so much may Allah reward you.